# CustomRoleProvider: Working with AddUsersToRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to work with the two string arrays passed into AddUsersToRoles.

Here's what I think I need to do:

- First get the int UserID for the string[] usernames.

  Then get the int RoleID for string[] roles.

  Concat the two arrays together.

  Save the data to UserRole (a database that contains 3 columns: UserRoleID, UserID, RoleID).

Here's what it looks like:

`//override and implement a custom 'adduserstoroles' from the abstract method in   RoleProvider`

```
    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        int[] userid;

        foreach(var username in usernames)
        {
            User user = AuthRepository.GetUser(username);
            //Error 1: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CustomAuth.AuthRepository.GetUser(string)'

            userid = user.ID;
            //Error 2: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

        }

        int[] roleid;

        foreach(var rolename in roleNames)
        {
            Role role = db.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleName == rolename).SingleOrDefault();

            roleid = role.RoleID;
            //Error 3: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

        }

        var userroles = userid.Concat(roleid).ToArray(); 

        foreach(var userrole in userroles)
        {
            UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
            db.UserRoles.Add(userRole);

        }

    }
```

Now, I don't know if I'm going off the deep end on this. I've searched around for examples of how others have handled this type of thing but I can't find any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for error 2 and 3, you're trying to assign a plain old int to an array of ints, which doesn't make any sense. You probably just want to make userid and roleid List's of ints

```
List<int> roleid = new List<int>();
```

Then in the foreach loops, you can just

```
roleid.Add(user.ID);
```

and

for error 1, it looks like AuthRepository isn't a static class, so you'd need to create an instance of it before using it.

```
foreach (var username in usernames) 
{
    AuthRepository repository = new AuthRepository();
    repository.GetUser(username);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was playing with List<int> but I didn't realize that I needed the .add() to assign the int to the list. I'm very grateful. I've struggled with this for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I create a free i to keep track of how far through the array you are, then change the foreach to:

```
int[] userid = new int[usernames.length];
i=0;
    foreach(string username in usernames)
    {
        User user = AuthRepository.GetUser(username);

        userid[i] = user.ID;
        i++;
    }
int[] roleid = new int[...];
i = 0;
```

That way you will fill up the userid array to match the username array. (and do the same for role)

Are you sure concat is what you want?  Wouldn't it be better to declare a 2d array

int[ , ] roles = new ...

then fill it in, as concat just adds the two arrays together so you have a much longer array.

---

edit:

concat will take the second array and add it to the end of the first producing a longer array, so if you had the arrays:

```
userid[1,2,3]
roleid[7,8,9]
```

then userid.concat(roleid).ToArray would give you a longer array
result = int[6] {1,2,3,7,8,9} Which is presumably not what you want.

I would use lists, I like lists. And I would then create your userRole class, which presumably has 3 ints in it (for the UserRoleid, Roleid, and userid) then I would iterate in a loop with a counter, and use that to create your userRole and add it to the DB:

```
UserRole userRole;
i = 0;
foreach(int id in userid)
{
     userRole = new UserRole();
     userRole.id = i;                 // Note this line and the next two could be done 
     userRole.user = id;              // in the constructor, passing i, id, roleid[i]
     userRole.role = roleid[i];        
     db.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
     i++;
}
```

though I am not sure how the databse is set up so dont know if this would work.

Comment: A. I sort of see your point about iterating through each of the values in the array using usernames.length but I was wondering if it was safer or redundant (I don't know, I'm asking). B. I do not know if concat() is what I want. I'm not sure I follow your example. Are you saying the concat() array will produce be 0: userid[0], roleid[0] ...?

Comment: concat will take the second array and add it to the end of the first producing a longer array, so if you had the arrays:

userid[1,2,3]